# center image while keeping footer

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've been working on trying to get an image to center (was able to do that) while still having a footer that would stick at the bottom of the page.

I can't seem to figure out how to position the footer at the bottom, because of the way I'm positioning the image.

This is what I have:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:black;
    color: #463D38;
}

#Content {
    clear:both; 
    width:500px;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px;
    height:240px; 
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

#inner {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
}

#text-center{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the HTML code of the page:

```
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Content">
<div id="inner">
<img src="logo332.png" width="500" height="163">
</div>

<div class="footer">test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any pointers or suggestions on how I can have these two playing nicely with each other?

Much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to stick the footer, then you need to make it position:fixed;

Comment: can you show us your html code?

Comment: code seems no error. can you post any picture of that?

Comment: use relative positioning, then you can center your image properly + have a sticky footer. add your html code

Comment: I've added HTML (edited the question). Will add screenshot in a second.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke I just noticed your answer! Appears to work exactly as I wanted it! THANKS! Want to submit as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Glad it's what you needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick the footer, then you need to make it position:fixed;